# illegal non geometric in MySQL for linestring function

Tags: mysql, geospatial

Why is @pointA an illegal non-geometric? I think I defined it as a point? I'm trying to draw a square with some data from a few tables.

```
    set @rowscount = 3;
    set @negYval = (select Y_less from min_y where Row_no = @rowscount);
    Set @negXval = (select X_less from min_x where Row_no = @rowscount);
    Set @posYval = (select Y_greater from max_y where Row_no = @rowscount);
    Set @posXval = (select X_greater from max_x where Row_no = @rowscount);

    SET @pointA = (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@negXval," ",@negYval,")"))); 
    SET @pointB = (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@negXval," ",@posYval,")"))); 
    SET @pointC = (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@posXval," ",@posYval,")"))); 
    SET @pointD = (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@posXval," ",@negYval,")"))); 

    SET @Line1 = Linestring(@pointA, @pointB);

    Select @negYval, @negXval, @posYval, @posXval, X(@pointA), Y(@pointA), X(@pointB), Y(@pointB), X(@pointC), Y(@pointC), X(@pointD), Y(@pointD);
```

Edit 1:
This also didn't work, error is illegal non-geometric.

```
    SET @Line1 = st_geomfromtext(concat("linestring (", @negXval," ", @negYval,", ",@negXval," ",@posYval));'
```

Comment: what is the exact error? "Didn't work" doesn't help. Avoid every using "doesn't work" when asking for help - exact messages, behavior and correlating expected behaviour will also get answers quicker and more accurately. Which mysql version? Welcome to SO.

Comment: The Error message says illegal non-geometric as a says at the top of the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the closing `)` in the constructed string for linestring.

Here is full version that I've tested:

```
SET @negXval := -123.45;
SET @negYval := -45.67;
SET @posYval := -56.78;

SET @Line1 := ST_GeomFromText(concat('linestring (', @negXval, ' ', @negYval, ', ', @negXval, ' ', @posYval, ')'));

SELECT ST_AsText(@Line1);
```

Prints

> LINESTRING(-123.45 -45.67,-123.45 -56.78)

Comment: Much appreciated, I do still wonder why I wasn't able to create a line from two pieces of point data though, the text option feels more cumbersome somehow.

Comment: I have no idea, seems like MySQL - looks like geometry support in variables is broken. It seems to work if you construct the points inline:
```select LineString(
      (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@negXval," ",@negYval,")"))),
      (st_geomfromtext(concat("POINT (",@negXval," ",@posYval,")"))));```
or  ```select LineString( Point(@negXval, @negYval),   Point(@negXval, @posYval));``` - without using WKT strings at all.

Comment: Wow, searched for MySQL bugs - found this - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80697, fixed in 2016 in 5.8 version for ST_AsGeoJson at least. I've 5.7, cannot verify if your code works in 5.8.

Comment: Interesting! I really need to use 5.7 because we have some other tools designed to work with 5.7. Guess I will be sticking with text options.

Comment: Or construct points inline - as in my last example, that avoids any text. Just don't store them in variable.

Comment: thanks! I've got it all stored in a procedure now, avoiding text.